# API Gateway unauthorized when using token

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am trying to test an API Gateway endpoint, using Postman.

I'm trying to make use of the Hosted UI, and whilst I can get an access_token returned in the URL, using this in the Authorization Bearer Token, I simply get 401 Unauthorized responses.

The specific endpoint has the correct authorizer attached to it.

I even tried removing the authorizer all together, but still got the 401 response, so I'm quite confused, as that should have meant I don't need to pass any token with the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, despite the naming convention, `access_token` was the wrong token to use. I tried th `id_token` and that works.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Add an OAuth scope if you want to use the access token otherwise use an id token.

[From the documents](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html)

With the COGNITO_USER_POOLS authorizer, if the OAuth Scopes option isn't specified, API Gateway treats the supplied token as an identity token and verifies the claimed identity against the one from the user pool. Otherwise, API Gateway treats the supplied token as an access token and verifies the access scopes that are claimed in the token against the authorization scopes declared on the method.